# Japanese font to match copperplate

Tags: fonts, font-pairing, japanese

I need to find a japanese font that matches copperplate in english. would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to match the serifs Mincho would be a good place to start.

It's one of the more traditional Japanese fonts.

[image]

Matching fonts between languages is tricky because there are requirements for how characters are used and laid-out.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a good match, but for those kind of serifs,

[image: Copperplate Medium]

I can only suggest this:

[image: DynaComWare Yuugasou Std W5]

though is too curly...

Anyway, if you are interested, the typeface is 優雅宋 Ｓｔｄ Ｗ５ [ゆうがそう] ([Yuugasou Std W5](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=880)) from [DynaComWare](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/). I will keep looking for a better match.